# Redux - Access other reducer's data from the action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

in my e-commerce website i'm using react with redux and firebase for storing data and authentication, the user can add items to the cart and then visit the cart component, but after he logs out the items in the cart still the same, so i have to access the state of `cardReducer` from the `authReducer`

the auth actions:

```
export const signOut = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const card = getState().card
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS', card })
    });
  }
}
```

the card reducer:

```
const initState= []

const cardReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_POST':
      if (!state.includes(action.post)) {
        return [...state, action.post]; 
      }
      return state;
    case 'REMOVE_POST':
      return state.filter(post => post === action.post);
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do. You say you have to access the `cardReducer` state, but what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I basically want to clear the posts in the card reducer after logging out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add another case for clearing the cart in cardReducer.

```
case 'CLEAR_CART':
      return initState;
```

I assume, you have a cart Actions file too, in that define an action which clears the cart

```
export const clearCart = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
     dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_CART' })
  }
}
```

Then import that action in your auth Actions file, and call the action.

```
import { clearCart } from '..Cart Actions Path';

export const signOut = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const card = getState().card
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS', card })
      clearCart();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding a case to your `cardReducer` for the `LOGOUT` action. It will be triggered when you logout, and you can reset to `[]`. E.g.

```
case 'LOGOUT':
      return initState;
```